# Alternative to nonlinear least squares method

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling

I have the following objective function:
\begin{equation}
W( x, y) = p_1\big[p_2e^{(- p_3x - y/ p_4)}+(1-p_2)e^{(- c_1x)}\big( p_5 e^{(- y/ c_2)}+(1-p_5)e^{(y/ c_3)}\big)\big]
\end{equation}

where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are constants and $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5$ are parameters to be estimated.

I am using a nonlinear least square method (levenberg-marquardt) to estimate my parameters. I was wondering if the above equation can be solved differently. I cannot linearise it but is there any other alternative solution to make it converge faster than using nonlinear methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is partly linear and is better tamed by redefining the parameters as follows:

$$a=p_1p_2,b=p_1(1-p_2)p_5,c=p_1(1-p_2)(1-p_5),d=-p_3,e=-1/p_4.$$

Now we have

$$W(x,y)=a\exp(dx+ey)+b\exp(c'_1x+c'_2y)+c\exp(c'_1x+c'_3y).$$

If the parameters $d$ and $e$ were known, the model would be a multiple linear regression (with no constant term), for which we have explicit formulas.

Now for a choice of $d,e$, the linear regression yields a residue, let $R(d,e)$ and you have reduced the question to a minimization of a nonlinear bivariate function. (It is possible to compute the gradient and Hessian, but this will be a little tedious.)

---

You should probably focus on finding good initial values of $d,e$ and a tight range.

---

Also note that knowing approximate values of $a,b,c$, you can express $dx+ey$ in terms of the data, and form another linear regression problem to estimate $d,e$. From these, re-estimate $a,b,c$ and so on.

This is a mixed least-squares/fixed-point approach. I have no idea if it will converge (!)

Comment: Thank you Yves. I don't have a very strong mathematical background so let me see if I understood well. Assume that $d$ and $e$ are known, as you said the above formula is a multiple linear regression. In order to estimate the parameters $a,b$ and $c$ I can write the above equation in a matrix form? Note that $x$ and $y$ are vectors with 50 entries. So I'll have a system of equations W=Xc which is an overdetermined system with 3 unknowns and 50 equations.Can I then use Singular Value Decomposition to solve it for example?

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{c}W(x_1,y_1)\\ W(x_2,y_2)\\.\\.\\W(x_n,y_n)\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}exp(dx_1+ey_1)\hspace{0.2cm} exp(c'_1x_1+c_2'y_1)\hspace{0.2cm} exp(c'_1x_n+c_3'y_n) \\ \\.\\.\\ \exp(dx_n+ey_n) \hspace{0.2cm} \exp(c'_1x_n+c_2'y_n)\hspace{0.2cm} exp(c'_1x_n+c_3'y_n)\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\ b\\c\end{array}\right)$

Comment: @Gina: yes you can, and there are alternatives.

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of your explanation in which you have said that I can reduce it to a minimisation of a nonlinear bivariate function. You mean to first estimate $d$ and $e$ using a nonlinear method and then use those to estimate $a, b, c$ as I described above? If so, how I define the nonlinear bivariate function?

Comment: @Gina: it is the residue of the linear regression.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't follow this idea. The linear regression has 5 unknowns $a,b,c,d,e$, right?

Comment: @Gina: no, three.

Comment: Could you please explain this idea a bit more explicitly so I can understand better? When you are referring to the 3 unknowns you mean $a,b,c$? In this case you assume that you know already $d$ and $e$ right? If you have 3 unknowns then how to you minimise a nonlinear bivariate function?

Comment: I used the Singular Value Decomposition to solve the system of equations I had but the results make no sense at all. Could you please suggest an alternative method to try to solve it? I want to see whether an alternative solution will provide better results. Thank you.